# Why does my configurable widget on editing say "No options provided for this parameter"?

Tags: ios, macos, widget, ipados

I made a configurable widget with an intents definition file, intent handler class (with code to provide dummy test data), and created a custom type for a parameter for it.  I checked "options are provided dynamically".  When I edited the widget on my device and clicked choose, a message box displayed  "No option provided for this parameter", and the widget didn't display any choices to choose from.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was simple once I thought of it.  I had to add a property to the response to the configuration in the .intentsdefinition file, and set its type to my custom type.  Then my dummy test date appears when I click choose instead of the "No option provided for this parameter" message.

Answer (score 0):

For me the ConfigurationIntentHandling (auto generated) protocol was missing in the IntentHandler class;

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {
```